# Prevent new ancestor from destroying the descendant's height

Tags: html, css

This question is regarding inheriting a height from a parent in css.
 
I tried searching for a similar question, but was not able to find it.
I have to make 2 columns expanding 100% height of the browser window which I was able to achieve that by setting `html,body{height:100%}` and then subsequently inheriting that height into the `.file-info-columns` id by assigning the height to each and everyone of it's ancestors.

My html structure is -

```
<div id="body-contents">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 file-info-columns" id="file-display-col">
                Col1
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 file-info-columns" id="file-details-col">
                Col2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) CSS library.
The css for getting another element inherit that was something like -

```
#body-contents, 
#body-contents > .container-fluid, 
#body-contents > .container-fluid > .row,
#body-contents > .container-fluid > .row > .file-info-columns{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Currently, it looks something like this- 
[image]

[Here is a fiddle with the full code.(You might need to scroll down to see col2 block)](https://jsfiddle.net/26y3rsy5/4/)
 This is working as I expect.
The problem I have is, later on, if I create another `div` which is an ancestor to `.file-info-columns` and not add it as member in the above `height:100%` css rule, the `file-info-columns` shrinks it's height.
For example, If I add a `div` immediately inside `body-contents`,then it looks something like this - 
[image]
Here is a [fiddle that shows the same](https://jsfiddle.net/26y3rsy5/3/).
The solution to the above is something like this -

```
#body-contents, 
#body-contents > div,
#body-contents > div > .container-fluid, 
#body-contents > div > .container-fluid > .row,
#body-contents > div > .container-fluid > .row > .file-info-columns{
    height: 100%;
}
```

This seems really tedious, for every change that will be done.

Is there a way to avoid this or do this in a better way? because, any change to the parent, by me or someone else working on this project, would require that element to be added in the above style rule every single time. I think I am missing something really obvious.
Also, Is a solution possible using only css, and not resorting to JavaScript?

**EDIT**
I want to retain the height of the rest of the elements inside(I don't want them taking up the size of the browser screen)
.
To quote my problem in a line - Is there a way to set the height of a div the browser screen size and not be affected if there are new elements added as it's ancestors.

Comment: If you really want any element in `#body-contents` to have the docs `height` you could do `#body-contents > * {height: 100%;}`.

Comment: @DavidDomain I want only file-info-columns to get the full browser height. The rest of the elements can take need not be bothered with height property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that Bootstrap 4 will deal with this since they incorporate `flexbox`.

I haven't looked at BS4 but `flexbox` would do it something like:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#body-contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
#body-contents * {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.file-info-columns {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="body-contents">
  <div>
    <!-- <= this is the extra div -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 file-info-columns" id="file-display-col">
          Col1
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 file-info-columns" id="file-details-col">
          Col2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <= this is the extra div -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried out your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/26y3rsy5/6/).It changes the new elements divs heights as well. Basically I want to retain the id `file-display-col` 's height to that of the browser and not touch the height of any other fields. I will update my question since this doesn't seem clear enough.